# Preservar o valor de um contator regressivo com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um problema com um contador regressivo. O contador funciona com o tempo que eu coloco nele, mas quando o cliente atualiza a página, o contador volta ao tempo inicial.

Existe alguma possibilidade de preservar esse valor ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  HTMLNovo = '<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameBorder="0" src="http://blog.rs1.com.br/info/plugincount/index.html" height="60" width="159"></iframe>';
  $('.frete-gratis').prepend(HTMLNovo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frete-gratis">DIV1: </div>
<div class="frete-gratis">DIV2: </div>
<div class="frete-gratis">DIV3: </div>
<div class="frete-gratis">DIV4: </div>
```

Comment: O cliente faz login no servidor?

Comment: Não, é uma flag de exibição de promoção em um site, olhe o primeiro capacete desse site: http://www.rs1.com.br/shark

Comment: Você tem que receber esse horário do servidor e o contador lê desse valor, não tem outra forma, acredito eu.

Comment: Entendo, como poderia fazer isso ? Poderia pegar o horário da maquina ?

Comment: Julio o problema é que se fôr associado a um certo usuário só se ele fizer login. Dá para fazer no browser com o localStorage mas se o utilizador usar outro computador o programa não vai distinguir...

Answer (score -1):

Encontrei um script que vai lhe ajudar. Bom, ainda deve-se verificar as possibilidades, o mais correta seria trabalhar com banco de dados, onde você pegaria a data/horário fim e subtraísse da data/horário final, onde essas datas devem vir do servidor do banco de dados, pois a data/horário do computador cliente pode estar errada.

De qualquer forma segue um bom exemplo, mas ele atende se a promoção for no prazo de 24 horas. Vou tentar melhorar o código que eu achei nessa [pergunta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16173928/4428986), e contar os dias também.

```
   if (document.getElementById('countdownTimer')) {
    pad = function(n, len) { // leading 0's
        var s = n.toString();
        return (new Array( (len - s.length + 1) ).join('0')) + s;
    };

    var timerRunning = setInterval(

        function countDown() {
            var target = 22; // **defina aqui a hora final**
            var now = new Date();

            //Put this in a variable for convenience
            var weekday = now.getDay();

            if(weekday == 0){// Domingo? adiciona 24 horas
                target += 24;
            }//keep this before the sunday, trust me :>

            if(weekday == 6){//Sábado? adiciona 48 horas
                target += 48;
            }

            //If between Monday and Friday, 
            //check if we're past the target hours, 
            //and if we are, abort.
            if((weekday>=1) && (weekday<=5)){
                if (now.getHours() > target) { //stop the clock
                    return 0;
                }                
            }

            var hrs = (target - 1) - now.getHours();
            if (hrs < 0) hrs = 0;
            var mins = 59 - now.getMinutes();
            if (mins < 0) mins = 0;
            var secs = 59 - now.getSeconds();
            if (secs < 0) secs = 0;

            var str = pad(hrs, 2) + ':' + pad(mins, 2) + '.<small>' + pad(secs, 2) + '</small>';
            document.getElementById('countdownTimer').innerHTML = str;

        }, 1000
    );
}
```